# Checking whether the base class implements a certain interface using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

**UPDATE:**

As it turns out, I am an idiot. Instead of deriving from `BaseClass`, I made a typo and derived from another class with a very similar name -- let's say `BassClass`.

Many thanks to @canton7 for patiently guiding me through the debugging process.

---

Here is some sample code:

```
using System;

public interface SomeInterface {}

public class SomeAttribute : Attribute
{
}

[SomeAttribute]
public class BaseClass : SomeInterface
{
}

[SomeAttribute]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
}
```

Through inspecting the syntax node that represents `DerivedClass`, I want to be able to know that `DerivedClass` implements `SomeInterface`, by virtue of its being derived from `BaseClass`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SemanticModel semanticModel = context.Compilation.GetSemanticModel(candidateSyntax.SyntaxTree);
ISymbol candidateSymbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(candidateSyntax);

if (!ImplementsSomeInterface(candidateSymbol))
{
    // Do something
}

bool ImplementsSomeInterface(ISymbol symbol)
{
    return symbol is ITypeSymbol typeSymbol && typeSymbol.AllInterfaces.Any(i => i.Name == "SomeInterface");
}
```

`ImplementsSomeInterface` returns true for `BaseClass` but false for `DerivedClass`. `typeSymbol.AllInterfaces.Count()` is 1 for `BaseClass` and 0 for `DerivedClass`.

How should I implement the `ImplementsSomeInterface` method, so that it returns true also for `DerivedClass`?

Comment: `AllInterfaces` on `DerivedClass` should be giving you `SomeInterface`. Can you check whether the `DerivedType` symbol is in error? Can you check whether its `BaseType` is `BaseClass`?

Comment: @canton7 Sorry for the dumb question, but will you elaborate what you mean by this? `Can you check whether the DerivedType symbol is in error?`

Comment: Check `.TypeKind`, see if it's `Error`

Comment: @canton7 It returns `Class`.

Comment: OK good. Can you check whether `.BaseType` is `BaseClass`?

Comment: @canton7 Yes, indeed it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217903/discussion-between-canton7-and-my-g).

Comment: From chat, it turns out that the example wasn't quite correct: `DerivedClass` actually derived from a similar but differently-named class to `BaseClass`. Voting to close as caused by a typo, as I don't think this question will be helpful to others

Answer (score -4):

You can achieve it easily, using reflections:

```
var temp = typeof (B).GetInterfaces ().Contains (typeof (Isome));
```

If that's not the case, perhaps try write all of them to console, to check does it fetches those interfaces right.

Comment: The question is about Roslyn, not about reflection

Comment: The question is about Roslyn analyzers. The code being examined does not run.

Comment: (and with reflection, you'd use `IsAssignableFrom`)